# Implementing TableView Navigation with JSON data

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, xcode6

Good morning,

I followed the following [tutorial](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Implementing_TableView_Navigation_using_Xcode_Storyboards) to create a TableView Navigation successfully, but with that example, the data is coming from a static string:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.carMakes = [[NSArray alloc]
                     initWithObjects:@"Chevy",
                     @"BMW",
                     @"Toyota",
                     @"Volvo",
                     @"Smart", nil];

    self.carModels = [[NSArray alloc]
                      initWithObjects:@"Volt",
                      @"Mini",
                      @"Venza",
                      @"S60",
                      @"Fortwo", nil];

    self.carImages = [[NSArray alloc]
          initWithObjects:@"chevy_volt.jpg",
                      @"mini_clubman.jpg",
                      @"toyota_venza.jpg",
                      @"volvo_s60.jpg",
                      @"smart_fortwo.jpg", nil];
}
```

And that data is showing [like](http://www.techotopia.com/images/5/54/Iphone_ios_5_prototype_cell_running.jpg)

Currenlty I would like to display the data from my JSON output (that displays the latest entries from my MySQL database) like that:

```
[{"id":"15","user":"1","image":"http:\/\/farmaventas.es\/images\/farmaventaslogo.png","date":"2014-09-13"}]
```

How can I do that? I have tried to find a tutorial to follow but I'm unable to do that and that's why I'm asking your help because I'm lost at the moment.

I have my structure as the tutorial working with the "car example", and I also have my JSON output, I just only need help with how to send the JSON data to the TableView.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: your problem is solved or u need any assistance brother

Comment: Thanks @Anbu.Karthik. I still need help as you can see in my replies below I still need help with that because I need to put my JSON output to the info from carMakes, carModels and carImages to have a dynamic content from my database.

Comment: can u show ur code I optimize the your answer and solve your issue

Comment: I can't reach my MAC at the moment, but as I said, I'm getting the JSON output using NSURLConnection, and after that, I need to put the info [{"id":"15","user":"1","image":"http:\/\/farmaventas.es\/images\/farmaventaslogo.png","date":"2014-09-13"}] in those values in order to show them in my TableView. I will copy later my code here but If you can help me I will be much appreciated @Anbu.Karthik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is your output

```
[{"id":"15","user":"1","image":"http:\/\/farmaventas.es\/images\/farmaventaslogo‌​.png","date":"2014-09-13"}]
```

in your `VIewDidLoad`

```
 -(void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

self.carImages =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
self.carModels =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

}


NSData* serlizeJSONData; 
NSError * e;
```

**your JSON is started with NSArray  so I directly called  NSArray *jsonDict in Serialization**

```
NSArray *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: serlizeJSONData
                                                             options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                               error:&e];

    [self.carImages removeAllObjects];
    [self.carModels removeAllObjects];
for (int i=0; i<[jsonDict count]; i++)
        {

            NSDictionary *dict = [array objectAtIndex:i];

            [ self.carImages addObject:[dict objectForKey:@"image"]];
            [ self.carModels addObject:[dict objectForKey:@"date"]];

          }

   [your tableview reloadData]
```

Comment: I'm going to try with that @Anbu.Karthik. I hope it works. I also want to know where I have to put the second code. Thanks again.

Comment: Also, if I'm not able to do that with your code, can I ask for your help again @Anbu.Karthik? Regards.

Comment: sure bro , i surely hope with u

Comment: I mean the second part you write "your JSON is started with NSArray". Thanks again @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: actually your JSON o/p is started with array not a dictionary so that line I mentioned with u , what i try

Comment: @JulienKP - have a happy day bro